# Find all projective modules.

Tags: homological-algebra, projective-module

I asked a similar question earlier but I will be more specific this time.

> Let $A= \mathbb{C}[x]/(x^n -1)$. How can I describe all the principal projective modules of $A$?

If $M= (x)$ is a principal/cyclic $A$-module it can be proven that $M \cong A/\text{Ann}_{A}(x)$, but from here I am not making any progress, I am trying to use different equivalent conditions for a projective module but no further success, any hints?

Comment: Am I misunderstanding that $A$ is the group ring of a cyclic group, which is semisimple, so its projective modules are all direct sums of simple modules, and all of which are one-dimensional?

Comment: @KyleMiller Not quite sure if i understand your question but let me try to be a little more clear: $A$ is simply a quotient ring, and I am supposed to describe all its principal $A$-modules that are also projective, that is, all $A$-modules of the form $M=(x)$ that are projective. Maybe $x$ was misleading to use, I should have written $M=(a)$ as the generator for $M$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution based on the representation theory of finite groups indicated in the comment of Kyle Miller.

Let $G$ be the cyclic group of order $n$, generated by an element $g \in G$. Then we can prove that
$$f \colon \mathbb CG \overset{\sim}{\to} A,\ g \mapsto x$$
is an isomorphism of $\mathbb C$-algebras.
Hence $A$ is semisimple by the Maschke theorem and projective indecomposable $A$-modules are precisely simple $A$-modules. Now let $\zeta_n$ be a $n$-th root of unity and set
$$e_i := \frac{1}{n}\sum_{0 \le j < n} \zeta_n^{-ij}g^j$$
for $0 \le i < n$.
These are primitive idempotents of $\mathbb CG$ and $e_i\mathbb CG = \mathbb Ce_i$ are simple $\mathbb CG$-modules by the representation theory of finite groups. Conclusion: every projective $A$-module is semisimple and it is direct sum of some of $f(e_i)A = \mathbb Cf(e_i)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\operatorname{Ann}_A(a)$ (don't use the letter $x$ to denote two different things) has to be generated by an `idempotent` of $A$ since the exact sequence:
$$0\longrightarrow\operatorname{Ann}_A(a) \longrightarrow A\longrightarrow Aa\longrightarrow 0$$
splits. So it comes down to finding all idempotents of $\mathbf C[x]/(x^n-1)\simeq\mathbf C^n$.

*Some details:*

$\operatorname{Ann}_A(a)$ is generated by an idempotent because it is finitely generated, and for any prime ideal $\mathfrak p\in\operatorname{Spec} A$, $A_{\mathfrak p}\dfrac a1$ is a projective, hence free, $A_{\mathfrak p}$-module, so
$$\bigl(\operatorname{Ann}_A(a)\bigr)_{\mathfrak p}=\operatorname{Ann}_{A_{\mathfrak p}}\Bigl(\frac a1\Bigr)= (0)\enspace\text{or}\enspace A_{\mathfrak p}.$$
Now an ideal which is locally $0$ or $1$ is generated by an idempotent.

Comment: Can u explain why it has to be generated by an idempotent? I don't see that.

Comment: @Sodan: I've added some details.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I must admit I am still a little confused as this is new theory for me, if you have time I would like to ask for some more details. For instance, how does the maps look that make the sequence split? And how do you draw the conclusion that it is finitely generated just because the sequence splits?

Comment: For the first point, once you have an idempotent $e$ which generates  $\operatorname{Ann}_A a$, you have a decomposition $A=Ae\bigoplus A(1-e)$, aand the maps are just the projections onto the factors. For the second point, $\operatorname{Ann}_A a$ is finitely generated (cyclic indeed) because it is the image of the first projection (and anyway, your ring is noetherian – and even artinian since it's a finitely generated $\mathbf C$-algebra.

Comment: I don't know why I am having troubles to understand your answer :(, your point is, I get that $\text_{A}(a)$ is finitely generated, why is this important when you later price that the ideal is locally $(0)$, and how is the split exact sequence important in this answer? Please enlighten me, I am sure I am missing something.