# Ideal locally free of rank 0 or 1 implies idempotent

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

At the end of one of the answers to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2434722/find-all-projective-modules) MSE post, and also in the second paragraph of Section 1 of [this](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1969-022-02/S0002-9939-1969-0242807-2/S0002-9939-1969-0242807-2.pdf) paper, I think it is indicated that if $I$ is an ideal (maybe finitely generated, maybe projective as an $R$-module) of a ring $R$ (commutative with $1$) such that the localization $I_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is free of rank $0$ or $1$ for all prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}$ in $R$, then $I$ is an idempotent ideal (i.e. $I^2 = I$).

However the following appears to be a counter example to this: If we take $R = \mathbb{Z}$, and $I = (2)$, then $I$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module of rank $1$, hence any localization of $I$ at any prime ideal will also be free of rank $1$, but clearly $I$ is not idempotent as $I^2 = (4) \neq (2)$.

**Question:** What gives? Am I misreading something in these two references? Or is my counter example wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hypothesis here is not merely that $I_\mathfrak{p}$ is free of rank $0$ or $1$, but that it is equal as an ideal to $(0)$ or $(1)$.  That is, in the case where it is rank $1$, it is required to be equal to the entire ring.  That fails for $I=(2)$ if you localize at $\mathfrak{p}=(2)$.

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe I made that silly mistake! Thanks so much.